Raster calculator giving error "No reference layer selected nor CRS provided"
I want to calculate some vegetation index in QGIS. I use the raster calculator, but when I run the process it give me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterCalculator.py", line 129, in processAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("No reference layer selected nor CRS provided"))
_core.QgsProcessingException: No reference layer selected nor CRS provided

even if the layers have their own Reference system. How can I solve this problem?

You should provide more information about what exactly you have and what you did if you expect an answer. See [tour]
